# How to boost a Power Bank's maximum output voltage?

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, voltage-doubler, powerbanks

I have an Anker ~27Ah Power Bank which has 3 × (5v , 3A) power output.

Is it possible to connect the outputs in series and get 10v or 15v output with a current flow of 3A?

Comment: No. They are galvanically connected (shares ground) so you can not put them in series.

Comment: Ah != A; Voltage != Power. Anyway, what you want to do is actually increase power, and that's impossible.

Comment: @winny Thanks for your answer. Is there any third-party circuit that I can use in order to increase the output voltage? Or just use it to serie the output safely?

Comment: @MarcusMüller So sorry for misunderstandings. I've edited my question title and description. Check it out please. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @user12530749 can't put the outputs in serial, they're pretty certainly sharing the same ground. Exactly as winny said.

Comment: Ah is a measure of charge flow (or energy at a fixed voltage), not current flow. Something like 2.1A would be a measure of current.

Comment: @user12530749 Welcome to EE.SE. Please keep in mind that questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the 5 V outputs share the same ground hence they cannot be connected in series. To make it easier to understand you can think that the outputs are already in a parallel configuration and hence cannot be changed. What you can do however is use a boost converter, which increases/boost your voltage to a certain extent (depending on the IC used). To clarify, you can connect it to one of the 5 V outputs and increase voltage. The drawback is that the max current at the output will be capped (limited to an extent).

Further clarification is required on the use of AH units, AH is a measure of battery capacity. For example 3 AH means that by supplying 3 amp continuously; the battery can survive for an hour. However, this is a theoretical value as voltage decreases as the battery drains out. if the voltage decreases then so does the current when used on a resistive load. Anyways, your battery can supply more current than 3 A but it will last for less time.

Comment: I edited in the words "when used on a resistive load" on the second last sentence. A constant-power load such as a switching regulator would actually *increase* the current as the voltage falls.

Comment: ok...it is more clear to the readers now that i was referring to a resistive load.

Answer (score 1):

Not within the same power bank. The outlets all share the same ground, and internally, the same power. If you tried it, all you will do is short two of the outputs to ground which would trigger their USB fault current limiters (so no magic smoke would come out.)

If you had 3 separate power banks, then maybe it could work much like connecting 3 batteries in series.

Charging would be slightly more complicated though. You'd have to use 3 separate adapters that have floating secondaries (normal configuration for a wall-power charger, but not for a car adapter.) Just something to check on.

Answer (score 0):

The outlets are likely not current limiting. USB tends to work  on an honor system for current limiting. It's up to the device you plug into the source to limit itself. You could likely draw more than 3A from a single port if you don't care about over loading it. You should be able to use a boost converter to get 10V 3A or 30W (drawing over 5V 7A or 35W due to efficiency)

That said the ideal solution is to get a power bank that can do QC or USB PD, so it states it can do 5v/9v/12v etc and get a QC trigger module to force it into the voltage you want.